# How can I get a 3.4 version of pdb?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, pdb

I tend to use a Debian *wheezy* system, that ships with Python 2.6, 2.7 and 3.2.

However I'm developing now using a local installation Python 3.4 because has a very interesting advantage over Python 3.2.

The problem is that I don't know how to install such a thing as a `pdb3.4`. When I run `pdb3` over my Python 3.4 program, it runs as a Python 3.2 program, failing.

**I'm on the need of general Python advice on versions and multi-host (Ubuntu *precise* and *trusty*, and Debian *wheezy*) multi-version development, and I particularly need downloading and building a 3.4 version of `pdb`**, but I don't get to find any documentation on that.

Comment: pdb is a module from the standard library. There is no need to install it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every version of Python comes with its own `pdb` module. It is [part of the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html).

The version in the 3.4 standard library has no special advantages over the version that comes with 3.2 or 2.7. The last time `pdb` functionality was changed was in the 3.2 and 2.7 releases (the only thing missing in the 2.6 version is the [`skip` keyword argument to `pdb.Pdb()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#pdb.Pdb), and 3.3 added more tab completion support).

If you have a `pdb` command line, then that's just an alias for `python3 -m pdb`; you can use that with any of your versions:

```
python3.2 -m pdb yourscript.py
```

Debian and Ubuntu simply copy the `pdb` module to `/usr/bin/` with the Python version appended, so `/usr/lib/python3.2/pdb.py` is copied to `/usr/bin/pdb3.2`.

Comment: Actually I have seen that usage written somewhere, but I was confused by not finding any `pdb3.4` binary or script. You answer me, but I'm staring now to /usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py and /usr/lib/python3.2/pdb.py, the two resolution endpoints of my `pdb` and `pdb3`, and see many more things than just wrapping around a script with '-m pdb '. I wonder other user might need some contents additional to watch you answer me.

Comment: The rest of the module is well enough documented in the Python documentation I linked to.

Comment: The sentence _If you have a `pdb` command line, then that's just an alias for `python3 -m pdb`_ is not true. But maybe it is true in your particular system.

Comment: @galegosimpatico: Debian copies the whole `pdb` library to `/usr/bin/pdb<version>`. Running `python -m pdb` does the *exact same thing* as running the library as a script. Python modules can double up as scripts and can also be used as `-m modulename` on the command line, `pdb` does both.

Comment: @galegosimpatico: The module has a `__main__` test [at the bottom of the file](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/pdb.py#l1682) that handles being run as a script or with `python -m pdb`. If you use `diff -u /usr/bin/pdb3.4 /usr/lib/python3.4/pdb.py` you'll see that the files do not differ.